# MySQL match records with like operator

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

I have timestamp field in my table.

For example, I have one value in my table like this:

```
2013-08-11 16:18:00
```

Now I want result like this way:

> 2013-08-11 16:18

I don't want to match **second** in timestamp.

My Query is:

```
UPDATE n2jm0_cronjob_run SET state=0 WHERE crondate LIKE '2013-08-11 16:18:02'
```

**(Update from comments)**

I can't remove seconds directly from query

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL Datetime, remove seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166734/mysql-datetime-remove-seconds)

Comment: Do not use `like` with datetime values. Just do a comparison (using date time objects not strings). I am not a php person, but essentially: `WHERE crondate >= '2013-08-11 16:18:00' AND crondate < '2013-08-11 16:19:00'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cant remove seconds part from your datetime field at all, try this:

```
UPDATE n2jm0_cronjob_run SET state=0 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(crondate ,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')=
DATE_FORMAT('2013-08-11 16:18:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

`DATE_FORMAT('2013-08-11 16:18:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')` will be matching upto minute part only.

See this *[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/825e0/4)*

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE n2jm0_cronjob_run SET state=0 WHERE crondate LIKE '2013-08-11 16:18%'
```

Maybe like this,if I understood correctly.

Comment: Hey I can't remove seconds directly from query.

Comment: I need to match with 2013-08-11 16:18:02 but don't need to consider seconds.

Comment: In your answer you removed seconds that is not possible. I want to match with whole timespamp.

Comment: Ok so whats the problem with your original query,then?

Comment: I am executing cronjob every minute and cronjob fire every minute. That's why results not matching.

Comment: I`m really trying,but I`m not telepathic.You need to provide more explanations,because its not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Hey is it possible if 2013-08-11 16:18 match with 2013-08-11 16:18:02 update query. doesn't matter second.

Comment: @Manan What exactly do you mean by _`match`_. To my knowledge, solution given here exactly _matches_ your need.